# Full-width vertical navbar within col- on mobile devices

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've got a two column layout. The left column has a vertical navbar menu that is collapsible on smaller screens. Does anybody know how to make it full-width without the 15px padding on each side on mobile devises? I understand that this padding comes from the .col- classes, but if I change it to 0px, then the layout on bigger screens gets all ugly, without spaces.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">       
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block visible-xs" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-sidebar-navbar-collapse-1"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-bars"></i> Menu</button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-sidebar-navbar-collapse-1">
            some content here
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                 some content here
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                some content here
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                some content here
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried inserting:

`@media(max-width: 767px) {
    .col-xs-12 { padding: 0 }
}`

Since XS size is from 0 to 767 px, you could use no padding on those.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you! That nearly worked, but for some reason I'm getting some 15px space to the right. I've checked, it's coming from the rows in the second column. I've nested several columns inside it. Trying to sort it out.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have a wrong html markup see bootstrap documentation for further instruction

## Grid System

- **Rows must be placed within a .container (fixed-width) or .container-fluid (full-width) for proper alignment and padding.**
- **Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be immediate children of rows.**

Taken from [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

---

One solution is to use another class in the row element and remove the padding with custom media queries.

## Media Queries

**Min-Width:** Refers to everything greater than or equal to the amount given.
**Max-Width:** Refers to everything less than or equal to the amount given.

**col-xs-* :** Extra small devices phones | No need media query - ( < 768px ) 
**col-sm-* :** Small devices Tablets | `@media (min-width: 768px) {}` - ( >=768px )
**col-md-* :** Medium devices Desktops | `@media (min-width: 992px) {}` - ( >=992px )
**col-lg-* :** Large devices Desktops | `@media (min-width: 1200px) {}` - ( >=1200px )

Information about bootstrap 3 grid options [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options)

Comment: Thanks! You mean, I can't put a navbar inside of a column? I can't find any information about that...

Comment: I did not mean that. Read carefully. In your markup you have column class first and then row. This is wrong use of bootstrap. That is what I meant. The informations is on the links.

Comment: But it can be used if I want to nest several columns within a column, right?

Comment: I've edited the code, adding several columns within the second one.

Comment: See the Bootstrap documentation for nesting columns [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting)